# Cannot connect interface to Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, port, lidar

I am trying to connect and run a device (LiDAR) through Docker container since it needs Ubuntu 16 while my computer is Ubunutu 20.

I got the device to ping inside the docker container, but it is not recognised when I try to use it.

What I did:

Made Dockerfile with requirements (Added EXPOSE to expose all ports)

Built docker image using:
`docker build -t testLidar`

I then made a container using
`docker run -d -P --name test_Lidar (imagename)`

Then
`docker exec -t test_Lidar (device_ip)` works

I am able to ping my LiDAR IP inside the container, but when I do `ip a` I cannot see the interfaces connected to my machine.

Been stuck on this for 3 days, any suggestions?

*Note*: I have done the exact same steps but on an Ubuntu 16 machine. The only change was the `docker run` command had `--net host` instead of `-P` tag and my device worked perfectly. I feel like this is the root of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--net host` flag with `docker run` to attach the container to your host's networking stack and make it available in for other hosts in your network.

When you use `--net host`, you actually attach the container to your host's networking stack. By default, containers are attached to the `default` network of type `bridge` and can communicate with each other. You can then reach them only from your host using its ip addresses typically in subnet `172.17.0.0/16`.

Using `-P` actually binds exposed ports from a container with randomly selected free ports on your host. It should be used for exposing network services (eg. web server with port 80), but not for ICMP ping.

Comment: I did that, but when I do `ifconfig` inside the container through bash I cannot see my networking stack. How can I do that?

Comment: Which image do you use? Does it have `net-tools` installed?

Comment: I am using an image of Ubuntu 16 but I have a Dockerfile for additional dependencies. Yes net-tools is installed. When I do `ifconfig` I can only see eth0 and my localhost.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your use case. I have pulled `ubuntu:16.04`, installed `net-tools` inside and attached to my host's networking stack - I can see all the interfaces.

Comment: Fixed ! Gave you the green checkmark. I think it was a configuration issue, restarted docker and I could see interface